# Remove screen options tab if not admin

Tags: wordpress

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to remove the screen options tab in the post/page editor screen. I have found the following...

```
function remove_screen_options(){ __return_false;}
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options');
```

...but it removes the tab for all users. I would like to keep it for admins.

Regards,

John

Found the answer after collaboration of all of your efforts. Thank you.

```
get_currentuserinfo() ;
global $user_level;

function remove_screen_options(){ __return_false;}
if( $user_level <= 8 ) add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options');
```

Comment: WordPress has a dedicated Stackexchange website, see here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to conditionally check if the current user is an admin. If they aren't, then remove the screen options like so:

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
  function remove_screen_options(){ __return_false;}
  add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options');
}
```

Here are the official Wordpress docs detailing this function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin

Comment: Hi Glen, that didn't work neither; tab showing for all users. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Glen, `is_admin()` checks whether or not it's an admin page request. It has nothing to do with the current user's role.

Answer (score 3):

If you place the following snippet of code into your functions.php file, the Screen Options tab will disappear across the whole backend for all users except the admin. Having said that, it is a good practice to modify the php file of your child theme.

functions.php code:

```
function remove_screen_options_tab() 
{
    return current_user_can('manage_options' );
}   
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options_tab');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using capabilities the way Spencer suggests is usually the best method.

I'm thinking most people find roles & capabilities to be overly confusing. Using the actual user role with 'current_user_can' is more often than not your best bet for this or any other similar 'permission' based situation.

More often than not you will eventually end up adding/removing capabilities for a specific role, so if you ever give someone else the 'manage_options' capability, like perhaps the owner of the business, you all of a sudden gave them back the screen options as well (On a side note 'activate_plugins' is usually safe since it is only for someone that has level 10 access). You can check out all permissons on the [User Level Capability Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/User_Levels) at the bottom of the page to get a better grasp on it all.

Insert this in functions php:

```
if( !current_user_can('administrator') ) {
  // hide screen options for everyone but the admin
add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options_tab');
}

if( current_user_can('administrator') ) {
  // code here is shown to the admin
}
```

Following this format you can do the same thing with other roles. Also you dont have is change administrator to editor, author, contributor and subscriber, or any other roles you create.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(!current_user_can('manage_options')) add_filter('screen_options_show_screen', 'remove_screen_options');
```

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for your response but that didn't remove the tab for any user.

Comment: Try with !is_super_admin() or with !current_user_can('manage_options')

Comment: @Sam, `is_admin()` checks whether or not it's an admin page request. It has nothing to do with the current user's role.

Comment: @SpencerCameron true, and my hatred for wp is always more great

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the function `current_user_can`:

```
if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    // executes when user is an Administrator
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Adminimize, A WordPress plugin that lets you hide 'unnecessary' items from the WordPress backend.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

Comment: Adminimize is indeed a great plugin but it does not REMOVE the screen, just hide the menu with CSS. Although some people will claim the result is the same , it is essentially not ..

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS method for all the designers who rather stay away from php. It hooks into the admin_body_class and adds user-{role} as a body class.

functions.php code:

```
function hide_using_css_user_role( $classes ) {
global $current_user;
foreach( $current_user->roles as $role )
    $classes .= ' user-' . $role;

return trim( $classes );
 }
add_filter( 'admin_body_class', 'hide_using_css_user_role' );
```

Using this you can hide/show anything on the admin side per user role. In this case just use the :not css selector to make sure it's only hidden for non-admins.

```
function add_my_custom_user_css() {
ob_start(); ?>


<style type="text/css">
:not(.user-administrator) #screen-options-link-wrap, 
    :not(.user-administrator) #contextual-help-link-wrap  {
      display:none !important;
    }   
</style>


<?php
echo ob_get_clean();
}
add_action ( 'admin_head', 'add_my_custom_user_css', 999);
```

This is a pretty hacky way to do things but sometimes good for a temporary quick fix when you don't know the correct filter/action to hide or change things in wordpress. Adding the 999 will make sure it gets loaded at the end of the head tag. Note that it's only hiding using css, so don't use this for anything vitally important, because the code is still visible in the source file.

To remove it from the source use jquery instead. Just replace the styles above with the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($)) {
$( ":not(.user-administrator) #screen-options-link-wrap" ).remove();
}
</script>
```

'admin_body_class' already does us the favor of adding the page to body class, so to target specific pages as well, just check the source code and in the body tag you can see the current page. So for example, the dashboard uses .index-php. Just attach that to .user-administrator or whatever user you're targeting and you can customize the admin for any user just using css and javascript.